# Tefillin and Knots

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tefilin

1. Where in *halachah* is it stated that the *kesher shel yad* must be in contact with the *bayis* while they are *davening*?
2. Where in *halachah* is it stated that the *kesher shel yad* must also be in contact with the bayis even when the *tefillin* are put away?

Answer (score 6):

1. Shulchan Oruch Orach Chayim [Siman 27 Seif 2](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%96#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91)
2. Mishna Berurah [seif katan 10](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%96#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91)

Comment: Roaming Bear, what siman in Mishnah Berurah?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Siman 27, as mentioned by Roaming Bear in #1.